# Zipping a Maybe and Single leads to no result being emitted

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm making an Android application. I've to zip results from two places: One from `SharedPreferences` as a `Maybe` and other from the Room Persistence library(basically SQLite) as a `Flowable`.

I'm using the following code:

```
repository.getMaybe()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
    .toSingle()
    .zipWith(repository.getFlowable().single(DEFAULT VALUE), BiFunction { t1: DataType1, t2: DataType2 -> Pair(t1, t2) }
    .subscribe()
```

`repository.getMaybe()` is the `Maybe` source mentioned in the first paragraph. Likewise, `repository.getFlowable()` is the `Flowable` source.

I've tried using `doOnEvent`(to Log statements) on the `Maybe` source, the `Flowable` source and the zipped source. Only the `Maybe` source emits successfully. Others don't do anything at all.

The `Flowable` source is used in various other parts of my application and it is not at all an issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if `repository.getFlowable().single(DEFAULT VALUE)` produces any value on its own or not.

Comment: @akarnokd you're right. It doesn't produce any value on it's own. But when I remove the `single(DEFAULT VALUE)` part, it works normally.

Comment: I'd guess `repository.getFlowable()` is an infinite source so even if it signals one item, `single` requires a a finite source, otherwise it can't ensure there is only one item in the source. Try `getFlowable().first(DEFAULT VALUE)` instead.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks for your help. I've already answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Akarnokd, I tried removing the `single(DEFAULT ITEM)` part. It worked. On looking up the documentation at http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html, I came across this:

> single(T defaultItem)
>
> Returns a Single that emits the single item
>   emitted by the source Publisher, if that Publisher emits **only** a single
>   item, or a default item if the source Publisher emits no items.

Basically, the `Flowable` should emit only once. So, I'm using `firstOrError()` in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Maybe` does not return a value then calling `toSingle` would result in an `Single.error`. This would mean it would reach the `zipWith` as an arrow and it would never bother evaluating the value, since there is no value to zip with.

Comment: `Maybe` does return its intended value.

Comment: `doOnEvent` fires for both `onComplete()` and `onSuccess(value)`, `toSingle()` turns `onComplete()` into `onError`, making it ignore any transformations downstream.

Comment: I tried using `doOnError` to log the `Throwable`'s message. It didn't log anything. I've successfully logged the contents of the `Maybe` in `doOnEvent`. So, I guess the issue is not with the `Maybe` part.